Spectral Clustering: Finding the normalized minimum cut using the laplacian
I am trying to prove that finding the min $Ncut(A,B)$ for a edge weight graph $W$ with the diagonal matrix of edge degrees $D$ is equivalent to solving for $f \in \{a,b\}^n$ with the constraint that $f^T d = 0$ ($d$ is the vector of degrees, where $d_i$ is the degree of vertex $i$). $L = D-W$.
That is, I want to show $\frac{f^T L f}{f^T D f} = \sum_{i \in A, \ j \in B} W_{i,j} \cdot \left(\frac{1}{d(A)} + \frac{1}{d(B)}\right)$. It's pretty intuitive that this holds for the case where $a = 1/d(A)$, $b = 1/d(B)$, but if I don't have those values already, I can't say that for sure.
So far I have that because $f^T D \mathbf{1} = 0$, I know that $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{d(B)}{d(A)}$. I also deduced
$$f^T L f = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i,j} W_{i,j} (f_i - f_j)^2 = \sum_{i \in A, \ j \in B} W_{i,j} \ (a-b)^2 /2 = cut(A,B) (a-b)^2 / 2$$.
$$f^T D f = a^2 d(A) + b^2 d(B)$$
So, this gives me $$\frac{f^T L f}{f^T D f} = \frac{1}{2} cut(A,B) \frac{(a-b)^2}{a^2 d(A) + b^2 d(B)}$$
This gives me the $cut(A,B)$ part with sort of normalization term. I'm just not sure how to get from $\frac{(a-b)^2}{a^2 d(A) + b^2 d(B)}$ to $\left(\frac{1}{d(A)} + \frac{1}{d(B)}\right)$ as desired.
